# Express-Gateway: missing scopes under egContext - apiEndpoint.scopes

Tags: express-gateway

I want to force the add of a filed in the req.body, according to the scope of the credentials. I have 2 Apps (App1 and App2), and based on who is using my API, I want to programmatically add a field in the req. So credentials of App1 has scope `app1`, and `app2` in App2's scopes.

Moreover, I have 2 Environments, with different endpoints. Both App has access to both Ends (using different credentials). So I first choose the Env (using `dev_env` or `my_env` scope), then I verify which App is accessing (checking `app1` or `app2` scope).

To do that, I use expression `apiEndpoint.scopes.indexOf('app1')>=0`. that actually is not working, since the condition is always *false*. So for debugging purpose, I put the content of `apiEndpoint.scopes` as additional field in the `req.body`, to see what there is in that.

And I see that `apiEndpoint.scopes` has just `["my_env"]`, not "app1". Why?

So I have

```yaml
http:
  port: ${PORT:-8080}
  host: ${HOST:-localhost} 
apiEndpoints:
  myEndpoint:
    host: "*"
    scopes: ["my_env"] # I explain just this one here
  devEndpoint:
    host: "*"
    scopes: ["dev_env"] 
serviceEndpoints:
  myEndpoint:
    url:  'https://myserver'
policies:
  - basic-auth
  - cors
  - expression
  - key-auth
  - request-transformer
  - rewrite
  - oauth2
  - proxy
  - rate-limit 
pipelines:
  myEndpoint: 
    apiEndpoints:
      - myEndpoint
    policies:
      - request-transformer:  
        - 
           condition:
             name: allOf
             conditions:      
                 - # check if scope 'app1' is present. expression not working
                   #name: expression
                   #expression: "apiEndpoint.scopes.indexOf('app1')>=0"
          action:
            body:
              add:
                available_scopes: "apiEndpoint.scopes" # debug of available scopes.
```

And the content of req.body is

```js
{"available_scopes": ["my_env"]}
```

'app1' is missing!

==== update 1
If in `req.body.available_scopes` field I put "consumer", I got this:

```js
{
"type": "application",
"isActive": true,
"id": "....",
"userId": "...",
"name": "...",
"company": "...",
"authorizedScopes": [
      "my_env"
    ]
}
```

So it talks about "authorizedScopes", where are the others? How could I see them?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have specified the scopes `my_env` and `dev_env` for the apiEndpoints myEndpoint and devEndpoint (respectively), and these are the only scopes Express Gateway expects you to care about, so the other scopes associated with the user/app credential are not exposed.

You could add the app1 and app2 scopes to each path in the config file and then act based on whichever scope is set for the credentials of the connecting app:

```yaml
apiEndpoints:
  myEndpoint:
    host: "*"
    scopes: ["my_env","app1","app2"]

  devEndpoint:
    host: "*"
    scopes: ["dev_env","app1","app2"]
```